Derivation of a conditional expectation
Setup. I have 3 random variables $Z_1,Z_2,\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, where
$$
(Z_1,Z_2)\sim
\mathcal{N}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\Sigma=
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11},\Sigma_{22} \\
\Sigma_{22},\Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\right).
$$
Let $Y=Z_1+\epsilon$, and $\epsilon$ is independent of $(Z_1,Z_2)$. I would like to compute $\mathbb{E}[Z_1|Z_2,Y]$.
Question. Given that $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, then using the joint property of Gaussians, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z_1\,|\,Z_2=z_2,Y=y]
=z_2+\frac{\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{22}}{\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{22}+\sigma^2}y.
$$
Can we still computing $\mathbb{E}[Z_1|Z_2,Y]$ if we only know that $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon^2]=\sigma^2<\infty$ (without knowledge of the distribution).
My attempt. By the law of total expectation, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Z_1\,|\,Z_2=z_2,Y=y]
&=\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[Z_1\,|\,Z_2=z_2,Y=y,\epsilon]\Big] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[y-\epsilon] \\
&=y.
\end{align*}
Is this correct? The final answer feels wrong to me because it does not tally with the case of a Gaussian $\epsilon$, but I don't know where I went wrong.
EDIT. I found my mistake, the law of total expectation formula used is wrong and should be this instead:
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[Z_1\,|\,Z_2=z_2,Y=y,\epsilon]\Big|Z_2=z_2,Y=y\Big],
$$
but I am still unable to evaluate $\mathbb{E}[Z_1\,|\,Z_2=z_2,Y=y]$ explicitly.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but I think your formula for $$\mathbb{E}[Z_1,|,Z_2=z_2,Y=y]$$ is incorrect. E.g. if $\Sigma_{12}<0$ a higher $z_2$ should cause a lower conditional expectation, whereas your formula suggests higher $z_2$ always means higher conditional expectation.

I have $\Sigma_{12}=\Sigma_{21}=\Sigma_{22}$ here.

My apologies, I missed that.

Your formula only holds for a normally distributed $\varepsilon$, not for an arbitrary distribution with finite variance, so there won't be a proof independent of distribution.
Suppose $\varepsilon$ is $\sigma$ with probability $\frac12$ and $-\sigma$ with probability $\frac12$. Then
$$\mathbb{E}[Z_1\,|\,Z_2=z_2,Y=y]=$$
$$P(Z_1=Y-\sigma|Z_2=z_2,Y=y)(y-\sigma)=P(Z_1=Y+\sigma|Z_2=z_2,Y=y)(y+\sigma)$$
As $y$ becomes large, $P(Z_1=Y-\sigma|Z_2=z_2,Y=y)$ goes to $1$ (this is regression to the mean) so asptotically $\mathbb{E}[Z_1\,|\,Z_2=z_2,Y=y]$ approaches $y-\sigma$. Similarly, as $y \to -\infty$, $\mathbb{E}[Z_1\,|\,Z_2=z_2,Y=y]$ aysmptotes to $y+\sigma$.
This shows it cannot be linear in $y$, like your formula, as a linear function cannot have two different asymptotes.
